# Rajawali: convert 3D object position to 2D point

Tags: android, 3d, rajawali

With Rajawali, I want to display a TextView via the Android UI on 3D object coordinates on the screen.

So, basically, I want to convert 3D coordinates to 2D coordinates.
I was wondering if there are any shorthands in Rajawali to do this, or otherwise what are the methods to use.

Also, it would be cool that if the object is not visible from the camera point of view, the TextView is hidden.

Comment: This is fine if you are 2d only.In 3d, if you place as a textview, it might not give the correct depth perception.  Did u succeed in this ?

Comment: Absolutely not. That said, I've seen a man that have shared his code to raster a text into a 3D plane, that's better than nothing.
I also found mathematical solutions, it's pretty complicated but not unrealizable.

Comment: did you try unproject the 3d coords to scren coords ?

Comment: If I remember correctly, yes, that was the approach I chose. However that was a school project and I've never finished it, and the source code must be on some old university SVN repository that I no longer have access to :D